# Can this condition infer that the matrix is Hermite?

Tags: matrices, symmetry

$\boldsymbol{A^H A=AA^H}$ does this imply that $\boldsymbol{A}$ is Hermite matrix? Why?

$\boldsymbol{A^H}$ is the conjugate transpose of $\boldsymbol{A}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your condition means that the matrix is normal. Not all normal matrices are hermitian (for example, pick your favorite unitary matrix).

Comment: You mean it is orthonormal matrix? Why? Could you please give the prove?

Comment: No. You should do at least the last epsilon of work yourself.

Comment: Normal matrix is *defined* that way: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix

Comment: A matrix that is normal always has the form $U+iV$ where $U$ and $V$ are Hermitian, and $UV = VU$.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously counterexample: Skew-Hermitian matrices and unitary matrices.